# vue dynamic image binding

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The original code used an image in a menu like so:

```
<img
  :alt="$t('more')"
  class="mobile-plus-content visible-xs"
  src="../../../assets/img/plus79.png"
/>
```

This compiles to:

```
src="data:image/png;base64,the image"
```

I changed it to:

```
v-bind:src="mobileImage(id)"
```

And in my script:

```
methods: {
  mobileImage(id) {
    console.log('id:', id);
    return logic ? plus : minus;
  },
```

It logs the id but I don't know what to return here. Where should I put the png because vue is no longer compiling it into static resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In script I did:

```
const minus = require('@/assets/img/minus-1.png');
const plus = require('@/assets/img/plus79.png');
```

and in mobileImage:

```
return this.isMenuOpen(id)
  ? minus
  : plus;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI. You can also use require in the template tag:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img v-if="isMenuOpen(id)" :src="require('@/assets/img/minus-1.png')"/>
    <img v-else :src="require('@/assets/img/plus79.png')"/>
  </div>
</template>
```